# Check that a bitmask flag is zero

Tags: objective-c, bit-manipulation, bitmask, bit-masks

I'm getting data from a server. The first bit indicates whether a message was read or not read: 1 for "read" and 0 for "not read". The second bit says whether the message was edited or not.

So I'm trying to read the statuses:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MessageStatus) {
    MessageStatusReaded   = (1 << 0), // => 00000001
    MessageStatusEdited   = (1 << 1), // => 00000010
};
```

But I don't understand how to check zero values (for not read and not edited).

Comment: put an enum `MessageStatusNone   = 0` ?

Comment: but I need at least two more statuses - MessageStatusNotRead and MessageStatusNotEdited.